# c# slow socket speed

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write a client/server file transfer system. Currently it works, and I've profiled it, and I can't seem to send data any faster than maybe 2-4 megabytes per second. 
I've tuned my code so that I can read data from the disk in the hundreds of megabytes per second, and the performance wizard shows nothing above a 1-3 between my disk read and my socket write, so my code is setup(it would seem) to push out data as fast as the nic/cpu/motherboard whatever could handle it.

I suppose the question is, why isn't that the case?

Here is some code, so that you can get an idea of what I've got set up here.

## Socket code(as streamlined as I can make it)

```
namespace Skylabs.Net.Sockets
{
    public abstract class SwiftSocket
    {
        public TcpClient Sock { get; set; }

        public NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }

        public const int BufferSize = 1024;

        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        public bool Connected { get; private set; }

        private Thread _thread;

        private bool _kill = false;

        protected SwiftSocket()
        {
            Connected = false;
            Sock = null;
            _thread = new Thread(Run);
        }
        protected SwiftSocket(TcpClient client)
        {
            _Connect(client);
        }
        public bool Connect(string host, int port)
        {
            if (!Connected)
            {
                TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
                try
                {
                    c.Connect(host, port);
                    _Connect(c);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            _kill = true;
        }
        private void _Connect(TcpClient c)
        {
            Connected = true;
            Sock = c;
            Stream = Sock.GetStream();
            _thread = new Thread(Run);
            _thread.Name = "SwiftSocketReader: " + c.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            _thread.Start();
        }
        private void Run()
        {
            int Header = -1;
            int PCount = -1;
            List<byte[]> Parts = null;
            byte[] sizeBuff = new byte[8];
            while (!_kill)
            {
                try
                {
                    Header = Stream.ReadByte();
                    PCount = Stream.ReadByte();
                    if (PCount > 0)
                        Parts = new List<byte[]>(PCount);
                    for (int i = 0; i < PCount; i++)
                    {
                        int count = Stream.Read(sizeBuff, 0, 8);
                        while (count < 8)
                        {
                            sizeBuff[count - 1] = (byte)Stream.ReadByte();
                            count++;
                        }
                        long pieceSize = BitConverter.ToInt64(sizeBuff, 0);
                        byte[] part = new byte[pieceSize];
                        count = Stream.Read(part, 0, (int)pieceSize);
                        while (count < pieceSize)
                        {
                            part[count - 1] = (byte)Stream.ReadByte();
                        }
                        Parts.Add(part);
                    }
                    HandleMessage(Header, Parts);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    Connected = false;
                    if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                    break;                    
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Connected = false;
                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                    break;
                }
            }
            HandleDisconnect();
        }
        public void WriteMessage(int header, List<byte[]> parts)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[8];
                //Write header byte
                Stream.WriteByte((byte)header);
                if (parts == null)
                    Stream.WriteByte((byte)0);
                else
                {
                    Stream.WriteByte((byte)parts.Count);

                    foreach (byte[] p in parts)
                    {
                        sizeBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(p.LongLength);
                        //Write the length of the part being sent
                        Stream.Write(sizeBuffer, 0, 8);
                        Stream.Write(p, 0, p.Length);
                        //Sock.Client.Send(p, 0, p.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                _kill = true;
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                _kill = true;
            }
        }
        protected void WriteMessage(int header)
        {
            WriteMessage(header,null);
        }
        public abstract void HandleMessage(int header, List<byte[]> parts);
        public abstract void HandleDisconnect();

    }
}
```

## File Transferer code(the class that sets up the socket, loads the file etc)

```
namespace Skylabs.Breeze
{
    public class FileTransferer
    {
        public String Host { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string Hash { get; set; }
        public FileStream File { get; set; }
        public List<TransferClient> Clients { get; set; }
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public int TotalPacketsSent = 0;
        public long FileSize{get; private set; }
        public long TotalBytesSent{get; set; }
        private int clientNum = 0;
        public int Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)(((double)TotalBytesSent / (double)FileSize) * 100d);
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler OnComplete;
        public FileTransferer()
        {

        }
        public FileTransferer(string fileName, string host)
        {
            FilePath = fileName;
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
            FileName = f.Name;
            Host = host;
            TotalBytesSent = 0;
            try
            {
                File = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, BufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan);
                File.Lock(0,File.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorWindow er = new ErrorWindow(e);
                er.ShowDialog();
            }

        }
        public bool Grab_Next_Data_Chunk(ref byte[] buffer, out int size, out long pos)
        {
            lock (File)
            {
                pos = File.Position;
                size = 0;
                if (pos >= FileSize - 1)
                    return false;
                int count = File.Read(buffer, 0, (FileSize - pos) >= FileTransferer.BufferSize ? FileTransferer.BufferSize : (int)(FileSize - pos));
                //TotalBytesSent += count;
                size = count;
                TotalPacketsSent++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        public bool Start(int ConnectionCount)
        {
            Program.ServerTrace.TraceInformation("Creating Connections.");
            if (Create_Connections(ConnectionCount) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
            File.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            FileSize = File.Length;
            Clients[0].Start(this,0);

            List<byte[]> parts = new List<byte[]>(1);
            parts.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(FileSize));
            Clients[0].WriteMessage((int)Program.Message.CFileStart, parts);

            Program.ServerTrace.TraceInformation("Sent start packet");

            for (clientNum = 1; clientNum < ConnectionCount; clientNum++)
            {
                Clients[clientNum].Start(this, clientNum);
            }
            return true;

        }
        private bool Create_Connections(int count)
        {
            Clients = new List<TransferClient>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                TransferClient tc = new TransferClient();
                if (tc.Connect(Host, 7678) == false)
                    return false;
                Clients.Add(tc);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public void AddClient()
        {
            TransferClient tc = new TransferClient();
            tc.Connect(Host, 7678);
            tc.Start(this, clientNum);
            clientNum++;
            Clients.Add(tc);
        }
        public void RemoveClient()
        {
            Clients.Last().Kill();
        }
        public void AdjustClientCount(int newCount)
        {
            int dif = newCount - Clients.Count;
            if (dif > 0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<dif;i++)
                    AddClient();
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<Math.Abs(dif);i++)
                    RemoveClient();
            }
        }
        public void ClientDone(TransferClient tc)
        {
            List<byte[]> parts = new List<byte[]>(1);
            parts.Add(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FileName));
            tc.WriteMessage((int)Program.Message.CPartDone,parts);

            tc.Close();
            Clients.Remove(tc);
            if (Clients.Count == 0)
            {
                Program.ServerTrace.TraceInformation("File '{0}' Transfered.\nTotal Packets Sent: {1}", FilePath,
                                                     TotalPacketsSent);
                File.Unlock(0,File.Length);
                File.Close();
                File.Dispose();
                if(OnComplete != null)
                    OnComplete.Invoke(this,null);
            }

        }

    }
    public class TransferClient : Skylabs.Net.Sockets.SwiftSocket,IEquatable<TransferClient>
    {
        public FileTransferer Parent;
        public int ID;
        private bool KeepRunning = true;
        public Thread Runner;
        public void Start(FileTransferer parent, int id)
        {
            this.Sock.Client.
            Parent = parent;
            ID = id;
            List<byte[]> p = new List<byte[]>(1);
            p.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parent.FileName));
            WriteMessage((int)Program.Message.CHello, p);
        }
        public void Kill()
        {
            KeepRunning = false;
        }
        private void run()
        {
            while (KeepRunning)
            {
                List<Byte[]> p = new List<byte[]>(3);
                byte[] data = new byte[FileTransferer.BufferSize];
                int size = 0;
                long pos = 0;
                if (Parent.Grab_Next_Data_Chunk(ref data,out size,out pos))
                {
                    p.Add(data);
                    p.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(size));
                    p.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(pos));
                    WriteMessage((int)Program.Message.CData, p);
                    Parent.TotalBytesSent += size;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            Parent.ClientDone(this);
        }
        public bool Equals(TransferClient other)
        {
            return this.ID == other.ID;
        }

        public override void HandleMessage(int header, List<byte[]> parts)
        {
            switch (header)
            {
                case (int)Program.Message.SStart:
                    {
                        Runner = new Thread(run);
                        Runner.Start();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        public override void HandleDisconnect()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to stress that in FileTransferer.Get_Next_Data_Chunk there is almost no delay, it reads really fast, in the 100's of megabytes per second.
Also, the WriteMessage for the socket is streamlined and fast as I believe humanly possible.

Maybe there is a setting or something? or a different protocol?

Any idea's would be more than welcome.

I forgot to mention, this program is being built SPECIFICALLY for LAN environments, which have a max speed of 1000Mbps(or bytes, I'm not sure, that would also be nice if someone would clarify that as well.)

Comment: Well, there's the obvious question: How fast is your network?  Post some iperf results, because those represent the upper limit you should be hoping to approach.

Comment: You forgot to remove `Thread.Sleep(10);` ? IF you just want to give other threads a chance to run, do `Thread.Sleep(0)`.

Comment: I would reconsider some of those public mutable properties.

Comment: Also, if you really want it fast as possible, go for UDP instead of TCP, but you will have to reconcile that the data received is correct indeed. Normally a MD5 or some other hash is ok for this. Read up on the bittorrent protocol.

Comment: You can also try converting the `List<byte[]>` into a single `byte[]` before sending, else you may end up sending tiny packets.

Comment: Well what I got was 65.9 Mbits/sec.

Comment: @leppie the reason for the Thread sleep is so it doesn't kill the CPU. I'm running between 1-100 threads concurrently.

Comment: Also, as a test, remove File IO out of the equation, and just send some premade `byte[]` in memory.

Comment: @ChaosPandion There isn't an issue with the code being slow, I've ran it through the performance profiler.

Comment: @kelton52: Do Thread.Sleep(0) or 1 or -1 (I cant recall the exact value).

Comment: @kelton52 - That was general advice not relating to your question.

Comment: @leppie I've already tested just reading the IO and not sending, and I was pulling 100+megabytes per second(that was with 100 threads, each taking turns calling it).

Comment: @ChaosPandion Which ones specifically? They were all designed for caching so I can do the least amount of IO calls as possible.

Comment: @leppie Converting the List<byte[]> into a single array would actually waste CPU time, and that was my bottleneck before. Array coping is very expensive, especially since I'm copying files that are in the gigabytes.

Comment: @kelton52 - It seems like at the very least `Sock` should be `protected`.

Comment: @leppie UDP shouldn't be needed. My cheap home computer can transfer ~118MB(bytes not bits)/sec over SMB with only ~1% cpu. Well, it does have an integrated Intel NIC. Anyway, TCP is not an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, your network speed will be bits per second, it's almost never bytes per second.

Second you're likely limited by having to constantly open and close the file with the IO readers. Unless you are running on a SSD this is going to cause significant increased overhead due to drive seek times.

To solve this, try to increase your buffer size to something larger as `1024` is quite small. I usually use around `262144` (256K) for my buffer sizes.

In addition to that, you will want to pipeline the file IO like this:

```
ReadBlock1
loop while block length > 0
    TransmitBlock1 in separate thread
    ReadBlock2
    Join transmit thread
end loop
```

Using the above pipeline you can usually get up to double your transmission speed.

When you implement pipelined file IO, you no longer need to worry about the problem of making your buffer size too large, unless your files are always going to be size of `< 2 * BufferSize`, since you say that you're dealing with in excess of 100mb files you need not worry about this case.

Other things you could do to improve this would be to use .

Also remember that in .NET file IO is very often synchronous despite use of threading.

For further reading see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx

Edit: just to add if you think the problem is the network and not the file IO, then just comment out the network part to make it appear instant, what speed do you then get? What about the reverse, what if you make your file reading just always return an empty `new byte[BufferSize]` how does that affect your copy speed?

Comment: Also, don't forget that there are 3 points of bottle neck: 1) Reading Files; 2) Network IO; 3) Writing the file. Check all three and see which one is actually causing your bottle-neck it might not be the one that you expect.

Comment: Yeah it is synchronous, that's why I added a Lock around it, so that each thread didn't move the file pointer around and screw up my transmission. I've also eliminated the read as the bottleneck.

Comment: Also, transmiting a block, reading, then joining, then retransmitting sounds like a bottleneck waiting to happen. The idea was to use multiple threads concurrently, since read speeds are much higher then network speeds.

Comment: I used to have my bytes sent increment in the Get_Next_Data_Chunk, and it would give me numbers above 100MegaBytes per second. That means, that before it sends it's reading that fast, then the speed would drop as all the threads hit the Stream.Write.

Comment: Also, the way I'm reading the file, I've ran it through the Visual Studio preformace tests, and .01%-.1% of the application time is spend in that method. about 1-3% is spent in my send. I don't have a flow bottleneck, the method I chose for getting the file data from the file and to the socket is about as fast as it gets, and I'm fairly confident on that.

Comment: Well I get fast speeds if I increase my Buffer to 1mb anyways. I turned it down because I thought it might be hurting my Network speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the distributed file system example, [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/987ff2245685/ExamplesConsole/DFSTest.cs), in [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net), an open source network communication library. If you enter something large for the test packet, like 200mb, it should max out your connection during transfer. Once the test is complete it will give you the average transfer rate. If that is still only a few MB per second then there may be something wrong with your connection.